# Artifactory keeps asking for credentials everytime

Tags: visual-studio, artifactory, credentials, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a project which maintains NuGet packages in Artifactory. I work on Visual Studio 2022 and every time I try to open "Manage Nuget Packages", a pop-up shows up asking me for Artifactory credentials.

[image: Artifactory Authentication Pop-up in Visual Studio 2022]

Is there a way I could save the credentials somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have started my quest by visiting Microsoft's doc for Nuget. I have found the solution in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-setapikey).

According to this, we can run the following command to -

> Save an API key for a given server URL into NuGet.Config so that it doesn't need to be entered for subsequent commands.

```
nuget setapikey <key> -Source <url> [options]
```

Once we run this, it will create an entry in the `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file (for Windows) and for Mac/Linux, `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config` or `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`.

Or, we could create the following entry directly within the above `Nuget.config` file like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
    <add key="JFrog" value="https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local" />
  </packageSources>
  <apikeys>
    <add key="https://xyz.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/nuget/nuget-local" value="YOUR_JFROG_API_KEY" />
  </apikeys>
</configuration>
```